# value gets submitted through form, then even after the value got submitted and gets displayed, in a form the value got submitted is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Sorry for the long title, but this is what happens:
I submit word "hello", then hello gets displayed. Then in a form, it still says "hello". I'm not sure why this is happening. Is this django problem or some javascript code is needed for this...?Here's my full code I think is causing this problem. 
in my views.py

```
def post(request, slug):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=request.user)
        try:
            profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
            # if it's a OneToOne field, you can do:
            # profile = request.user.myprofile
        except MyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            profile = None
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
        post.save()      # and save it
        path = request.get_full_path()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(path=path)
        #comments = post.comment_set.all()
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
            parent_comment = None
            if parent_id is not None:
                try:
                    parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
                except:
                    parent_comment = None
            comment_text = comment_form.cleaned_data['comment']
            new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                path=request.get_full_path(),
                text=comment_text,
                post = post,
                parent = parent_comment)

        for c in comments:
            c.get_children()


        context_dict = {
            'post' :post,
            'profile' :profile,
            'comments' : comments,
            'comment_form':comment_form

        }

        return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

and in my post.html I have

```
<table class='table'>

{% for comment in comments %}

<tr><td>{{ comment.get_comment }} 
<br/><small>via {{ comment.user }} | {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago </small>
        {% if not comment.is_child %}
        <ul>
        {% for child in comment.get_children %}
        <li>{{ child.get_comment }} 
        <small>via {{ child.user }}</small>


        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <a href='#' class='reply_btn'>Reply</a>
        <div class='reply_comment'>
        <form method="POST" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Add reply'/>
        </form>
        </div>
        {% endif %}


</td></tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>
</div>



<div class = "col-sm-3">

</div>

    {% include 'footer.html' %}


<script>
{% block jquery %}
$('.reply_btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".reply_comment").fadeToggle();
  // $(".reply_comment").fadeToggle();
})
{% endblock %}
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Can someone please direct me where I should look.....thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you check if a form is valid or not you assign the form to include the POST data so it will still include this when you return back to the form (in case it needs to show errors). The easiest fix would be to reassign the form after your valid logic is done.

```
   comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        .. Valid logic ..
        comment_form = CommentForm()
```